# Object to String Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have a problem, i cannot convert the Object to a String "Javascript"
I recover the value of my input which I match to a line in my table
But I don't know how to convert this to String.
If someone can help me, it will be very nice !

Here's the code :

```js
function resultat(){

    var hu = document.getElementById("name").value; 
    console.log(hu)
    

    const codes = [
        {code: 'WDUJWGMWB', prix: 'Bon d\'achat de 1€'},
        {code: 'NYTELSRLD', prix: 'Bon d\'achat de 0.50€'},
        {code: 'YZOIRDBUX', prix: 'Bon d\'achat de 0.50€'},
        {code: 'BULSWBWTZ', prix: 'Perdu'},
        {code: 'VZKOYVJPJ', prix: 'Téléviseur 4K'},
        {code: 'NTZLCFOZL', prix: 'Bon d\'achat de 3€'},
        {code: 'XKKQZSAOR', prix: 'Porte-clé'},
        {code: 'UHXZUUEPX', prix: 'Bon d\'achat de 1€'},
        {code: 'CNUZPTOOB', prix: 'Bon d\'achat de 1€'},
        {code: 'CWAJTRDHK', prix: 'Bon d\'achat de 1€'}
      ];
      
      function gain(lot) {
        return lot.code === hu;
        
      }
      console.log(codes.find(gain));

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="10" size="30">
    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer le formulaire" onClick="resultat();">



    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: "I want to convert this to a string" is too vague. According to one of your comments to one of the answers below, you want to join `codes.code` and `codes.prix` to form e.g. `"WDUJWGMWB Bon d\'achat de 1€"`. Please edit your question to include this. As you can see you're currently getting a bunch of answers that aren't actually helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(codes.find(gain))` will convert the object to the JSON string representation.

Check out [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for more info.

Based on your comment below, if you are just trying to output the values in the object, you can use string interpolation:

```
code = codes.find(gain)
if (code) {
  console.log(`${code.code} ${code.prix}`);
} else {
  console.log('code not found');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a toString() to your code: look up [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: What good would that do? While it will convert an object to a string, it won't convert one to a **useful** string.

Comment: i know, but i don't know where :/ i want to convert this : Object { code: "WDUJWGMWB", prix: "Bon d'achat de 1€" } to this : WDUJWGMWB Bon d'achat de 1€